neo4j connection using port 80 (Server responded HTTP)
I'm using Spring Boot (3.3.0) to connect to neo4j but I have this error

Server responded HTTP. Make sure you are not trying to connect to the
http endpoint (HTTP defaults to port 7474 whereas BOLT defaults to
port 7687)

neo4j installed on open shift and routing for port 7687 via port 80
this URL neo4j.test-myet.local:80 routing for localhost:7687
connection success with this link from neo4j desktop but from spring boot not working
Neo4jConfig:
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.repositories")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Neo4jConfig extends AbstractNeo4jConfig {

    @Bean(name = "recommendationDriver")
    @Nonnull
    public Driver driver() {
        Config config = Config.builder()
                .withoutEncryption()
                .withTrustStrategy(Config.TrustStrategy.trustAllCertificates())
                .build();

        return GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://neo4j.test-myet.local:80",
                AuthTokens.basic("neo4j", "neo4j123"),
                config);
    }


}

